# check_nrpe: ssocket time out after 10 seconds

Tags: linux, windows, nagios, nrpe

I have a Nagios core setup in my environment for monitoring Windows, Linux servers etc.

Recently i have configured a physical and swap memory monitoring using the plugin ./check_nrpe for windows servers. All the servers are working fine but for a specific server if i run the command i'm getting the error 'CHECK_NRPE: Socket timeout after 10 seconds.'

When i tried executing the plugin without the command and only with IP address as below also giving the same error.

[root@serverlibexec]# ./check_nrpe -H xx.xx.xx.xx
CHECK_NRPE: Socket timeout after 10 seconds.

Then i tried increasing the timeout value to maximum of 2000 using -t option which throws the same error :(.  I'm wondering how the check_nrpe plugin is becoming time out even after 2000 seconds :-/.

Kindly help me in resolving the same.

Thank you,

Comment: Not sure if it is related but you can try to tune the two parameters: 1. `verify mode = none` and 2. `insecure = true`. I have a SSL handshake problem when I want to monitor windows server with Nagios, but the problem gone after changing these settings.

Answer (score 0):

The Nagios server can't connect to the NRPE service on the server you are monitoring.

1. Check that the NRPE service in running on the destination server
2. Check that you have configured allowed_hosts correctly on the destination server so that the Nagios server is allowed connect (nrpe.cfg)
3. Check that no firewalls are blocking the connections

My guess is that its Number 2.

Comment: Thank you for your response! 1. But the NRPE port 5666 is listening on the server. I can get the telnet results and if i try nmap, the port is in open status as well. 2. Since i'm checking on the windows server, i have the NSC.ini configuration file configured with the correct allowed_hosts value which is the IP address of the Nagios server. What else could be the reason for this issue! :(

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is some permissions thing in the Windows OS that is preventing the NRPE check from running, or a typo of some sort in the NRPE config file. Is Windows Firewall completely disabled?

Comment: Yes, the Windows Firewall is completely disabled. And the command definition in the file wouldn't be wrong as it is common for all the servers and only this particular server is having issue.

Comment: You are probably going to have to look into doing a tcpdump so.